# Class or interface expected at the end of the first set of closing brackets

Tags: java, android

Keep getting a class or interface expected error at the end of the first set of closing brackets, I have a feeling it has to do with the onCreate method, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.

```
package shake.shake;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static Button ShakeButton1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);
    OnClickButtonListener();
    }
    }
    public void OnClickButtonListener()
    {
    ShakeButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ShakeButton);
    ShakeButton1.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intentSecondActivity = new       
    Intent(MainPage.this, ShakePage.class);
                    startActivity(intentSecondActivity);
                }
    }
    );
}}
```

Comment: This sort of error usually means you have mismatched curly braces.  Go through carefully and check which `}` matches which `{`.

Answer (score 0):

you have extra braces here

```
public class MainPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static Button ShakeButton1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);
    OnClickButtonListener();
    }
    } <-------- extra brace.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better having a look at codes before posting.

Your method  `public void OnClickButtonListener()` is outside the class `MainPage`. Move that method inside your class.